# Trouble generating thumbnail image in google drive add-on

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am working on an add-on for google drive using Google Apps Script.

I'd like to be able to show a thumbnail preview for a file in my sidebar. According to my understanding of the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image#setimageurlurl), I must encode the thumbnail as a base64 url, then pass it to `setImageUrl()` to display properly.

Here is how I currently create my image data string:

```js
var thumbnailBlob = file.getThumbnail()
var thumbnailBlobBytes = thumbnailBlob.getBytes()
var thumbnailBlobType = thumbnailBlob.getContentType()
var encodedThumbnailUrl = "data:" + thumbnailBlobType + ";base64" + Utilities.base64Encode(thumbnailBlobBytes)
```

I then pass `encodedThumbnailUrl` into a card widget like so:

```js
  var fileCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
     .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader().setTitle(fileName))
     .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
                 .setHeader("File Info")
                 .addWidget(CardService.newImage().setImageUrl(encodedThumbnailUrl).setAltText("No preview available")))
     .build()
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work correctly, and my add-on displays "No preview available" every time. I think I am following the documentation exactly.

Does anyone know what the issue is here? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, I think that the line of `var encodedThumbnailUrl = "data:" + thumbnailBlobType + ";base64" + Utilities.base64Encode(thumbnailBlobBytes)` might be the reason of your issue. In this case, `encodedThumbnailUrl` returns `data:{mimeType};base64{base64Data}`. I think that `,` is required to be put after `base64`. Because `Utilities.base64Encode(thumbnailBlobBytes)` returns the base64 data without including `,` at the top letter. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var encodedThumbnailUrl = "data:" + thumbnailBlobType + ";base64" + Utilities.base64Encode(thumbnailBlobBytes)
```

#### To:

```
var encodedThumbnailUrl = "data:" + thumbnailBlobType + ";base64," + Utilities.base64Encode(thumbnailBlobBytes)
```

-In this case, `;base64` is modified to `;base64,` like [this official document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/image#setimageurlurl).

Comment: That was exactly it. Thank you.

Comment: @abrezey Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.